# How to know the php version associated with particular version of XAMPP without installing on windows 10?

Tags: php, xampp, magento-2.3

I want to install magento2.3 on localhost windows ,but for that I need either of the following versions of php  ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 .

which is not available in latest version of xampp.

So instead of randomly downloading older versions of xampp and then installing .I want to know Is there any source where I can get this info that which version of PHP does this xampp contains before downloading/installing?

Comment: Unless some functions are deprecated you code should work with newer versions. You can also look for alternatives like wamp.

Comment: It tells you right beside download button: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Looks as though this should help - https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the following link:

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

2. Find the version you are interested in downloading you can find the PHP version under the Version Header.
   [image]
3. For more information click the "What's Included?" button to the left of the download button.

[image]

Comment: I am talking about older versions. Not the latest ones.